# Multiupload - Carriervawe, Rails, Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have implemented single image upload in my app using `carrierwave` `fog` and `amazon S3`.
This solution uploads single image directly to `amazon S3`.

Now, question is, how to extend it with **`multiupload`** ?

I know about this gem [S3 multipart](https://github.com/maxgillett/s3_multipart), but prefer simple and proven solution, where I do not need to refactor my existing code...

Can you pls share what solutions worked for you as the best one ?

```
<div id="post">
  <label><%= t('dashboards.index.new_post') %></label>
  <div>
  <%= form_for(@post, :html => { :multipart => true })  do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :text, :rows => '3', :placeholder => t('dashboards.index.new_post_placeholder'), :class => "post-text" %><br/>


  <%= f.label      :image %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %> <br/>
      # place for multiple uploads



  <%= f.label :tag_tokens, 'Tags' %>
  <%= f.text_field :tag_tokens %> <br/>

  <%= f.submit t('dashboards.index.send_message'), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for selection of multiple image you need to add

```
:html => { :multipart => true}
```

in your form as,

```
<%= form_tag(add_multiple_profile_image_path(:id=>@profile.id), :html => { :multipart => true}, :id => "profile_image_form") do %>
```

also in your image tag i.e file_tag you need to add as: :file, multiple: true AS,

```
 <%= file_field_tag :profile_image, as: :file, multiple: true, :id=>"profile_image", name: 'profile_image' %>
```

that's it. Now select multiple file and upload multiple image.